# Design session expiration service

Tags: java, performance, architecture, software-design

I have integration with video stream provider. The flow is following: user requests a stream url, next we on behalf of user, request it from stream provider and return to the user. Next, we should prolong the stream id (session) every 10 secs. To minimize interaction with the client and because of slow network, we want to do this session prolongation on behalf of the user. So let's say, user will trigger one request per 2-5 mins, at the same time server will trigger session prolongation requests every 10 secs.

The question is in possible design of such service. I have not found better solution other than just simply iterate over all available session keys periodically and call prolongation service.
But this approach has disadvantages when user count will be really big it could slow down processing. Also, it is hard to scale with such an approach.

Maybe you have ideas about how to overcome this? Or please propose a better solution

Comment: "But this approach has disadvantages when user count will be really big it could slow down processing." I suspect you'll run out of bandwidth for the video streams long before your requests become a bottleneck.

Comment: video stream actually use bandwidth of the stream provider it is not our services, so we only return stream url and that is all

Answer (score 1):

I would write the keep alive as a single self contained piece of code, that will call the keep alive every x number for seconds for y amount of time before ending itself, where x, y and the keep alive endpoint are startup parameters.

Each time the user triggers a request - kick one of these off in the background. How you package that is determined on your deployment environment and how you intend to manage scaling out (background thread, new process, server-less function, etc.).

You may need to maintain some state info in a cache for management purposes (don't start a new one if one is already running, hung process states, etc.).